# Подгрузка внешних JS скриптов "по событию"

Tags: javascript

Хочу реализовать следующий подход - подключать некоторые внешние скрипты только если на странице присутствуют DOM элементы использующие их (с определенным классом). Например загружается страница и если присутствует хоть один элемент document.querySelector('.ymaps-geolink') подгружается API Geolink Yandex. Таким образом я хочу предусмотреть в скрипте десятки разных хуков которые могут и не использоваться в текущем проекте, но если уж понадобились для подключения достаточно прописать только нужный класс у элемента.

Как лучше это реализовать на чистом JS кросс-браузерно, с поддержкой старых браузеров, чтобы работало кэширование и пр.? Какие на ваш взгляд у такого подхода минусы/подводные камни?

```html
<script src="https://api-maps.yandex.ru/2.1/?lang=ru_RU&load=Geolink"
 type="text/javascript"></script>

<span class="ymaps-geolink">
   Москва, ул. Крылатские холмы, 26
</span>
```

Примерно что я хочу (извиняюсь за php синтаксис)

```
$plugins=[
    ".ymaps-geolink"    => "https://api-maps.yandex.ru/2.1/?lang=ru_RU&load=Geolink",
    ".tooltip"          => "https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/tooltip.js",
    ...
    ...
];


function onload(){
    foreach($plugins as $k=>$v){
        if( document.querySelector($k) ){
            include_once($v);
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: Интересно, зачем тебе поддержка ***API Geolink Yandex***  в старых браузерах?

Comment: Мысль интересная, но webpack всё равно лучше, потому что он умеет объединять в один и сжимать множество подгружаемых файлов.

Comment: @Air, конкретно Geolink приведет только для примера. Ну а что нет так если будут подсвечиваться адреса и в IE 8,9,10? Если конкретно Geolink их не поддерживает (не пробивал пока), то будет кучка других плагинов.

Comment: Я тоже *ностальгирую* по по старому... )))

Comment: [requirejs](https://requirejs.org/)

Answer (score 2):

Исходя из поставленной задачи, предположу, что у вас существует некая ассоциативная коллекция, где ключ - предполагаемый класс, а значение - ссылка на javascript файл, необходимый, для обслуживания конкретного элемента.

Я бы сделал следующим образом:

1. Проитерировать коллекцию оставив только те элементы, классы которых присутствуют на странице. Таким образом мы получим список всех скриптов, которые необходимо использовать для страницы.
2. Перебрать полученную коллекцию и для каждого элемента динамически создать html тэг, подключающий файл.

```js
'use strict';

/* коллекция: объект, где имя свойства соответствует искоемому классу, а значение - обрабатывающиму скрипту */
let scriptCollection = {
  redColor: 'red-color.js',
  removeElement: 'remove-element.js',
  alert: 'alert.js'
}

const dynamicScript = (collection) => {

  let scripts = []; /* коллекция необходимых скриптов */

  /* собираю коллекцию необходимых скриптов */
  for (let key in collection){
    if (document.querySelectorAll(`.${key}`).length){
      scripts.push(collection[key]);
    };
  }

  /* добавляю скрипты на страницу */
  scripts.forEach((item) => {
    let scriptTag = document.createElement('script');
    scriptTag.setAttribute('src', item);
    scriptTag.setAttribute('async', '');
    document.body.appendChild(scriptTag);
  });
}

/* вызов функции */
dynamicScript(scriptCollection);
```

```html
<html>
<head>
    <meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html; charset=utf-8">
    <title>Pointer</title>
    <style>
        body{
            display: flex;
            flex-direction: column;
            justify-content: center;
            align-items: center;
        }
    </style>
</head>
<body>
    <div class="redColor">123</div>
    <div class="removeElement">123</div>
    <div class="alert">123</div>
</body>
<script defer src="index.js"></script>
</html>
```

Answer (score 1):

Есть такой вариант...

```js
document.getElementById('demo').innerHTML += '<div class="new-element">New element!</div>';

var jsHelp = document.getElementById('jsHelp');

function elemSearch(elemClass) {
  var elem = document.getElementsByClassName(elemClass);

  if (elem[0].className === elemClass && elem.length > 0) {
    var script = document.createElement('script');
    script.src = 'js/new-script.js';
    jsHelp.appendChild(script);
    document.getElementById('demo').innerHTML += '<br>Элемент [' + elem[0].className + '] обнаружен :)<br>Скрипт [' + script.src + '] подгружен :)</div>';
  }
}

// Поиск элемента
elemSearch('new-element');
```

```html
<div id="demo"></div>
<div id="jsHelp"></div>
```

Answer (score 1):

Рабочий и компактный вариант для вашей задачи:

```
<script class='lazyScripts' data-src="https://api-maps.yandex.ru/2.1/?lang=ru_RU&load=Geolink"></script>

<span id="ymaps-geolink">
  Москва, ул. Крылатские холмы, 26
</span>

<script>
window.addEventListener('load', function () {

    //если в документе есть ymaps-geolink
    if (document.body.contains(document.getElementById('ymaps-geolink'))){
        [].forEach.call(document.getElementsByClassName('lazyScripts'), function (element) {
            element.setAttribute('src' , element.getAttribute('data-src'));
        });
    }

});
</script>
```

(так же можно прикрутить асинхронный таймаут)